# Device to device push Notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a simple app in my two iPhones. My app contains only a button i want to send push notification to another device when i click the button. I have already created the project in firebase console.

In ViewController:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String) {
        // Set up the message content
        let message = ["to": token,
                       "priority": "high",
                       "notification": ["title": title,
                                         "body": body,
                                         "badge": 1,
                                         "sound": "default"]] as [String: Any]
        // Serialize the message to JSON
        guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message, options: []) else {
            print("Failed to serialize message to JSON")
            return
        }
        // Create the request object
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send") else {
            print("Failed to create URL object")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=<YOUR_SERVER_KEY>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        // Send the request
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to send notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("Notification sent successfully")
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    @IBAction func sendNotification(_ sender: Any) {
        print("gfcyfc")
        sendPushNotification(to: "5277df78e6354334eb84d5644c349d34c83f102d9abfbe5843c7cac5af1f27e0", title: "Hello", body: "Hello How are your")
    }
}
```

In App delegate:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { success, _ in
            guard success else{ return }
            print("Registration Successful")
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        messaging.token { token, _ in
            guard let token = token else { return }
            print("Tokennnnnnnnn\(token)")
        }
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Convert device token to string format
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        print("Device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}
```

How to send push notification to another device when i tap the button on one device?

I tried a lot of things but nothing works always i got an error message:

> APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '230481463908'. Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.